# mysql privilege to kill processes of other users

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a percona mysql database.  The version is 5.5.29-29.4-log.

I have created a user called admin which should be able to kill processes initiated by other users, i.e worker.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON *.* TO 'admin'@'ip_' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password';
```

It does had the process privilege, which I thought would do the trick. But, I can see this error

```
/* SQL Error (1095): You are not owner of thread 7480126 */
```

Would anyone be able to help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/kill.html)

> If you have the PROCESS privilege, you can see all threads. If you
>   have the SUPER privilege, you can kill all threads and statements.
>   Otherwise, you can see and kill only your own threads and statements.
>
> You can also use the mysqladmin processlist and mysqladmin kill
>   commands to examine and kill threads.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) for privilege granting - search for SUPER.